# How to run a shell script by just typing its name, as opposed to sh [scriptname]?

Tags: unix, sh

So I just started learning UNIX and need a very basic question answered! I have spent hours searching for the correct way, but it seems I cant really get my head around it!

I have script called "contactdetails". I would like to run it by just typing in "contactdetails" in any directory, but the only way I can run it is by typing in "sh contactdetails".

Now I've heard I should add "#!/bin/sh" to the top line of my script, yet that has not worked. I have also been told I need to add it the $PATH environmental variable. I don't really understand what that means, and I when I type "echo $PATH" I get "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games".

When I try to create a directory/file in the "/usr" directory, I get the message "Permission Denied". I logging onto UNIX via my works server, so is that the problem? Is there a way for me to run the script by just typing its name as opposed to sh itsname?

Thanks in advance!

edit: I have also changed permissions to executable (chmod 755 contactdetails) if thats of any relevance! And i'm using PuTTY!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make it executable with

```
chmod +x contactdetails
```

and have the directory it is in, in your path e.g. if your script is in `/dir/with/script`

```
   export PATH=$PATH:/dir/with/script
```

If you add this line to your `.bashrc` it will set `PATH` up for every bash shell

or put it in `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin`,`/usr/sbin`,`/usr/bin`,`/sbin:/bin` or `/usr/games` (you will need to do this as `root` user)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply!
I have made it an executable, and whenever I try to make a directory in my $PATH (which im guessing is anything in /usr ?) it says permission denied!

Comment: You dn't have to make the directory, just replace  /dir/with/script with the directory the script is in e.g. /home/user2489783/bin

Comment: Perfect! The export PATH=$PATH:/dir/with/script command worked!

Thank you for the help everyone, you solved my headache!

Answer (score 0):

Gotta copy that script (with the shebang in it, of course) into one of the paths in `$PATH`. Like this:

```
cp myscript /usr/bin/
```

If you don't have write permission on those directories, then that's it. Or you can set your `$PATH` to include your very own folder as well:

```
set PATH="$PATH:/path/to/mydir"
```

Answer (score 0):

/usr is owned by the root, hence you have no access there. You need to be have credentials in order to write into that directory.

$PATH contains the directories that your OS checks when you issue a command that does not have a complete path. You can add a directory to path with $PATH = $PATH:Additional directory.

The preferred way to do it is as H2CO3 suggested and you should always make your script executable as parkydr suggested.

Answer (score 0):

while you can put your scripts anywhere, my practice is to use my $HOME/bin, and when i add that information to my profile, i save the existing PATH before expanding it.   add these two lines to your $HOME/.profile:

```
ORIG_PATH=${ORIG_PATH:-$PATH};   export ORIG_PATH
PATH=$ORIG_PATH:$HOME/bin
```

so that should you have to revisit your profile:

```
$ . $HOME/.profile
```

the first line above has saved your ORIG_PATH and successive revisits to the profile don't grow your PATH indefinitely.